# iOS Swift - moving image with slider

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uislider

I have some problems moving an UIImageView using a slider. This is my code I'm currently using:

```
@IBOutlet weak var titanic: UIImageView!

...

let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
let titanicWidth = titanic.bounds.size.width
let viewcenter = titanicWidth / 2
let slidervalue = CGFloat(sender.value)
let value = (screenWidth * slidervalue * (1.0 - titanicWidth / screenWidth)) + viewcenter
titanic.center.x = CGFloat(value)
print(value)
```

Actually, I can move the image with this code, BUT: somehow the image always "jumps" back to it's origin position in the middle of the screen, without moving the slider at all... Do you have any idea, how this can happen? I already checked the inspector on the right for some strange attributes which may cause this effect, but no luck...

Comment: Did you use constrains for the imageView?

Comment: no, I even deleted the whole image and freshly added it... no effect at all

Comment: Ok when does it jump back? Just after releasing the Slider or if you change the sliders position?

Comment: a short time after releasing the slider

Comment: Hmm... and your print also prints that the value is equal to viewCenter?

Comment: why should they be equal? viewCenter is just to make sure the image can't get out of screen. Maybe the fact that I'm using OSX on a VMWare may cause this trouble, because of some mousedelay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you unchecked the "use AutoLayout" checkbox in your nib/storyboard, you are using AutoLayout, so the system adds constraints to your views if you don't.

When using AutoLayout you can't modify the frame/bounds/center of a view directly, or exactly what you describe happens. The next time something triggers a layout update, the view snaps back to the position defined by it's constraints.

You either need to turn off AutoLayout for the entire nib/storyboard, or add outlets to your constraints and change the constant value of the contstraint(s), then call `layoutIfNeeded()` on the view to make the constraint changes take effect.

I suggest adding outlets to the constraints. Switching to the older style struts-and-springs style form design is a big change, and one that will have large side-effects for your view controller. (Personally I **prefer** struts-and-springs style form design, but I force myself to use AutoLayout because that's the new way of doing things.)

Comment: The 3rd option is to create the `UIImageView` in code instead of laying it out in the Storyboard.  Then *Auto Layout* won't touch it and you can move it around with its frame.

Comment: Problem was caused by autolayout. Thx mate!

Comment: What solution did you end up using?